# Check if ScrollView is on the bottom, top or sides

Tags: android, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

How do I quickly and easily check if ScrollView or HorizontalScrollView is on its bottom, top or one of its side edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of API level 14 (Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich), you can use View's methods [canScrollHorizontally (int direction)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#canScrollHorizontally(int)) and [canScrollVertically (int direction)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#canScrollVertically(int)).

Example usage:

```
//Check if ScrollView is at the bottom
//If not, scroll to the top
if(scrollView.canScrollVertically(1))
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);
            }

        });
```

You can use this on ListView as well. For example, when working with messaging app, you may want to check if user is reading older messages, so when he will receive a new one, he won't be disrupted by scrolling to the bottom, but rather keeping him at current position.